How to Make a Terraform Script Reusable for Multiple Clients?
I am aware this is probably a VERY dumb question. But I can't seem to find the answer!
I've been studying Terraform for a few days now, and I've created a script to set up various infrastructure/resources like VMs, Resource Groups, VNets, Subnets, NSGs, etc. The script takes a name as a variable and creates everything I need - which is great.
My problem is, how do I make this script reusable? Currently, I am running it in VS Code, but I plan to move it to a DevOps pipeline soon. However, at the moment, I can only run it once.
For example, if I run the script with the client name "Yellow":
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "NewTest-RG1" {
  name     = "${var.Client_name}-RG01"
  location = "UK South"
}

Then, if I run the script again with the client name "Blue", I want it to create a new resource group called "Blue-RG01". Instead, it tries to destroy the "Yellow" resource group and then create the "Blue" one.
I want to be able to run this script repeatedly for many different clients without destroy any of the previous infrastructure created; but it seems I can only run it for one client at a time. I've come across mentions of Modules and Workspaces as possible solutions, but I haven't found a clear answer.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Have a different state file per client. (or environment) Remote state storage is a boon for this.

See Working with multiple environments in Terraform.

You can use a remote state file with a module to switch the workspace instead of deleting existing resources. By using this method, you can create new resources without destroying the existing ones, here is my output
**terraform workspace new yellow**,
**terraform workspace select yellow**,
**terraform apply**


So workspaces is the best way to go for this? This is also configurable and compatible via azure DevOps pipeline?

AFAIK, Yes, In DevOps Pipeline, you can use environmentVariables to select the workspace before terraform apply.

You can use a remote state file with a module to switch the workspace instead of deleting existing resources. By using this method, you can create new resources without destroying the existing ones.
├── 1.main.tf
├── modules/
│   └── my-module/
│       ├── resource.tf
│       ├── variables.tf
│     


main.tf

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {    
    resource_group_name  = "Automation_RG"
    storage_account_name = "sampledemotest"
    container_name       = "demo"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    access_key           = "=="
  }
}

locals {
  current_workspace = terraform.workspace
}
module "Block_client" {
  source      = "./my-module"
  client_name = "Block"
  location    = "eastus"
  count       = local.current_workspace == "Block" ? 1 : 0
}

module "blue_client" {
  source      = "./my-module"
  client_name = "Blue"
  location    = "eastus2"
  count       = local.current_workspace == "blue" ? 1 : 0
}
module "Green_client" {
  source      = "./my-module"
  client_name = "Green"
  location    = "eastus2"
  count       = local.current_workspace == "Green" ? 1 : 0
}
module "Red_client" {
  source      = "./my-module"
  client_name = "Red"
  location    = "eastus"
  count       = local.current_workspace == "Red" ? 1 : 0
}

my-module
resource.tf
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.client_name}-RG01"
  location = var.location
}

variables.tf
    variable "client_name" {
      type = string
    }
    
    variable "location" {
      type    = string
      default = "eastus"
    }

Terrafrom output:

If you want to create another resource group, just change the workspace using the commands below.
 terraform workspace new Red
  terraform workspace select Red
  terraform apply

Output:



Thanks for this! Is this the "standard" way this is done? Or can I JUST use workspaces?

You can use Workspace to create the same resources without destroying existing resources by changing the workspace.
